# Text segmentation in architecture floorplans

Tags: python, opencv3.0, text-recognition

For a complete floor plan analysis, text segmentation from the other graphic image is the crucial part. I have tried tesseract but it isn't that great, its because the text is in different orientations. I want the text to be separated as a layer with same dimensions as the floor plan image? Any suggestions how to do this?

thanks in advance....... :)

*[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IAiT.jpg*

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should add your code in the question description.

Comment: This is too broad. If you give sample images of controlled environments we might be able to help. How to perform text segmentation is not a valid question, it is too broad to be answereable in SO.

Comment: added an image :)

Answer (score 0):

As you ask without code, doing the same for this answer. A possible strategy would be to:

1. Use e.g. opencv to identify where text is.

   - In the example you give, you see that text is either within a room or on the outside as measurement.
   - Also, it are by far the thickest lines
2. Crop these regions
3. Turn the regions if height > width
4. Use Tesseract